# Looking for a query to to return the data value when the data changes otherwise return space ' '

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Database server type = SQL Server 2012 SP2

Here are the source tables.

```
  CREATE TABLE a 
  ( 
     e_id INT, 
     r_id INT, 
     d_id INT, 
     s_id INT 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE r 
  ( 
     id   INT, 
     NAME VARCHAR(50) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE d 
  ( 
     id       INT, 
     calldate DATE 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE e 
  ( 
     id      INT, 
     NAME    VARCHAR(50), 
     initial VARCHAR(5) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE s 
  ( 
     id        INT, 
     specialty VARCHAR(50) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO a 
VALUES      (8, 
             13, 
             9, 
             13), 
            (8, 
             13, 
             10, 
             13), 
            (8, 
             13, 
             11, 
             13), 
            (8, 
             13, 
             12, 
             13), 
            (8, 
             13, 
             13, 
             13), 
            (8, 
             13, 
             14, 
             13), 
            (10, 
             13, 
             15, 
             13), 
            (10, 
             13, 
             16, 
             13), 
            (10, 
             13, 
             17, 
             13), 
            (16, 
             13, 
             18, 
             13), 
            (16, 
             13, 
             19, 
             13), 
            (16, 
             13, 
             20, 
             13), 
            (9, 
             13, 
             21, 
             13), 
            (9, 
             13, 
             22, 
             13), 
            (9, 
             13, 
             23, 
             13), 
            (9, 
             13, 
             24, 
             13), 
            (16, 
             13, 
             25, 
             13), 
            (16, 
             13, 
             26, 
             13); 
INSERT INTO a 
VALUES
           (10,22,9,13), 
           (10,22,10,13), 
           (10,22,11,13), 
           (10,22,12,13), 
           (10,22,13,13), 
           (16,22,14,13), 
           (16,22,15,13),
           (16,22,16,13),
           (16,22,17,13),
           (9,22,18,13),
           (9,22,19,13),
           (9,22,20,13),
           (18,22,21,13),
           (18,22,22,13),
           (10,22,23,13),
           (10,22,24,13), 
           (9,22,25,13),
           (9,22,26,13);

INSERT INTO r 
VALUES      (13, 
             'Primary'), 
            (22, 
             'Secondary'), 
            (33, 
             'Prim Trd'), 
            (44, 
             'Sec Td'); 

INSERT INTO e 
VALUES      (8, 
             'Jack', 
             'JM'), 
            (9, 
             'Ace', 
             'AQ'), 
            (10, 
             'Mike', 
             'MM'), 
            (16, 
             'George', 
             'GH'),
            (18 ,'Bill',  'BK'  ); 

INSERT INTO s 
VALUES      (13, 
             'Pediatric'), 
            (28, 
             'EMT'), 
            (55, 
             'ER');

INSERT INTO d 
VALUES      (9   , '2015-01-09'),
            (10  , '2015-01-10'),
            (11  , '2015-01-11'),
            (12  , '2015-01-12'),
            (13  , '2015-01-13'),
            (14  , '2015-01-14'),
            (15  , '2015-01-15'),
            (16  , '2015-01-16'),
            (17  , '2015-01-17'),
            (18  , '2015-01-18'),
            (19  , '2015-01-19'),
            (20  , '2015-01-20'),
            (21  , '2015-01-21'),
            (22  , '2015-01-22'),
            (23  , '2015-01-23'),
            (24  , '2015-01-24'),
            (25  , '2015-01-25'),
            (26  , '2015-01-26'),
            (27  , '2015-01-27'),
            (28  , '2015-01-28'),
            (29  , '2015-01-29'),
            (30  , '2015-01-30')
```

Table A is a linking table that linKs Tables D, E, R, and S.

Table A

```
║ e_id │ r_id │ d_id │ s_id ║  
╠══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╣  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 16   │ 13   ║   
║ 10   │ 13   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 19   │ 13   ║   
║ 16   │ 13   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 13   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 13   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 13   │ 23   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 13   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 26   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 16   │ 13   ║   
║ 16   │ 22   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 22   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 22   │ 19   │ 13   ║   
║ 9    │ 22   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 18   │ 22   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 18   │ 22   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 23   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 22   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 9    │ 22   │ 26   │ 13   ║
```

Table D

```
║ id │ calldate   ║  
╠════╪════════════╣  
║ 9  │ 2015-01-09 ║  
║ 10 │ 2015-01-10 ║  
║ 11 │ 2015-01-11 ║  
║ 12 │ 2015-01-12 ║  
║ 13 │ 2015-01-13 ║  
║ 14 │ 2015-01-14 ║  
║ 15 │ 2015-01-15 ║  
║ 16 │ 2015-01-16 ║  
║ 17 │ 2015-01-17 ║  
║ 18 │ 2015-01-18 ║  
║ 19 │ 2015-01-19 ║  
║ 20 │ 2015-01-20 ║  
║ 21 │ 2015-01-21 ║  
║ 22 │ 2015-01-22 ║  
║ 23 │ 2015-01-23 ║  
║ 24 │ 2015-01-24 ║  
║ 25 │ 2015-01-25 ║  
║ 26 │ 2015-01-26 ║  
║ 27 │ 2015-01-27 ║  
║ 28 │ 2015-01-28 ║  
║ 29 │ 2015-01-29 ║  
║ 30 │ 2015-01-30 ║
```

Table E

```
╔════╤════════╤═════════╗  
║ id │ name   │ initial ║  
╠════╪════════╪═════════╣  
║ 8  │ Jack   │ JM      ║  
║ 9  │ Ace    │ AQ      ║  
║ 10 │ Mike   │ MM      ║  
║ 16 │ George │ GH      ║  
║ 18 │ Bill   │ BK      ║  
╚════╧════════╧═════════╝
```

Table R

```
╔════╤═══════════╗  
║ id │ name      ║  
╠════╪═══════════╣  
║ 13 │ Primary   ║  
║ 22 │ Secondary ║  
║ 33 │ Prim Trd  ║  
║ 44 │ Sec Td    ║  
╚════╧═══════════╝
```

Table S

```
|ID | Specialty |  
|---+-----------|  
|13 | Pediatric |  
|28 | EMT       |  
|55 | ER        |
```

Here is the query I was thinking would work, but generates errors:

```
SELECT d.calldate, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN s.id = 13 
                  AND r.NAME = 'Primary' THEN ( e.NAME ) 
           END) AS [Primary], 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN s.id = 13 
                  AND r.NAME = 'Secondary' THEN ( e.NAME ) 
           END) AS [Secondary], 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN s.id = 13 
                  AND r.NAME = 'Primary' 
                  AND ( ( e.id = (SELECT e1.id 
                                  FROM   a a1 
                                         INNER JOIN e e1 
                                                 ON e1.id = a1.e_id 
                                         INNER JOIN d d1 
                                                 ON d1.id = a1.d_id 
                                         INNER JOIN s s1 
                                                 ON s1.id = a1.s_id 
                                         INNER JOIN r r1 
                                                 ON r1.id = a1.r_id 
                                  WHERE  d1.calldate = CONVERT(DATE, 
                                                       Dateadd(dd, -1, 
                                                       d.calldate), 
                                                       101) 
                                         AND r1.NAME = 'Primary' 
                                         AND s1.id = 13) ) 
                        AND ( e.id = (SELECT e1.id 
                                      FROM   a a1 
                                             INNER JOIN e e1 
                                                     ON e1.id = a1.e_id 
                                             INNER JOIN d d1 
                                                     ON d1.id = a1.d_id 
                                             INNER JOIN s s1 
                                                     ON s1.id = a1.s_id 
                                             INNER JOIN r r1 
                                                     ON r1.id = a1.r_id 
                                      WHERE  d1.calldate = CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd 
                                                           (dd, 1, 
d.calldate), 
101 
) 
AND r1.NAME = 'Primary' 
AND s1.id = 13) ) ) THEN ' ' 
ELSE e.initial 
END) AS [PrimaryINIT], 
Max(CASE 
WHEN s.id = 13 
AND r.NAME = 'Secondary' 
AND ( e.id = (SELECT e1.id 
FROM   a a1 
INNER JOIN e e1 
ON e1.id = a1.e_id 
INNER JOIN d d1 
ON d1.id = a1.d_id 
INNER JOIN s s1 
ON s1.id = a1.s_id 
INNER JOIN r r1 
ON r1.id = a1.r_id 
WHERE  d1.calldate = CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(dd, -1, 
d.calldate), 
101) 
AND r1.NAME = 'Secondary' 
AND s1.id = 13) 
AND ( e.id = (SELECT e1.id 
FROM   a a1 
INNER JOIN e e1 
ON e1.id = a1.e_id 
INNER JOIN d d1 
ON d1.id = a1.d_id 
INNER JOIN s s1 
ON s1.id = a1.s_id 
INNER JOIN r r1 
ON r1.id = a1.r_id 
WHERE  d1.calldate = CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(dd, 1, 
d.calldate), 
101 
) 
AND r1.NAME = 'Secondary' 
AND s1.id = 13) ) ) THEN ' ' 
ELSE e.initial 
END) AS [SecondaryINIT] 
FROM   a 
       INNER JOIN e 
               ON e.id = a.e_id 
       INNER JOIN d 
               ON d.id = a.d_id 
       INNER JOIN s 
               ON s.id = a.s_id 
       INNER JOIN r 
               ON r.id = a.r_id 
WHERE  Datepart(mm, d.calldate) = 1 
       AND Datepart(year, d.calldate) = 2015 
GROUP  BY d.calldate
```

Here are the results that we are looking for from the query.

(Note that the Initial column is returning the column value only before and after a data changes):

**Desired Results from query.**

```
╔════════════╤═════════╤═══════════╤═════════╤═══════════╗  
║ callDate   │ Primary │ Secondary │ PrimINIT│ SeconINIT ║  
╠════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═══════════╣  
║ 2015-01-09 │ Jack    │ Mike      │ JM      │ MM        ║  
║ 2015-01-10 │ Jack    │ Mike      │         │           ║  
║ 2015-01-11 │ Jack    │ Mike      │         │           ║  
║ 2015-01-12 │ Jack    │ Mike      │         │           ║  
║ 2015-01-13 │ Jack    │ Mike      │         │ MM        ║  
║ 2015-01-14 │ Jack    │ George    │ JM      │ GH        ║  
║ 2015-01-15 │ Mike    │ George    │ MM      │           ║  
║ 2015-01-16 │ Mike    │ George    │         │           ║  
║ 2015-01-17 │ Mike    │ George    │ MM      │ GH        ║  
║ 2015-01-18 │ George  │ Ace       │ GH      │ AQ        ║  
║ 2015-01-19 │ George  │ Ace       │         │           ║  
║ 2015-01-20 │ George  │ Ace       │ GH      │ AQ        ║  
║ 2015-01-21 │ Ace     │ Bill      │ AQ      │ BK        ║  
║ 2015-01-22 │ Ace     │ Bill      │         │ BK        ║  
║ 2015-01-23 │ Ace     │ Mike      │         │ MM        ║  
║ 2015-01-24 │ Ace     │ Mike      │ AQ      │ MM        ║  
║ 2015-01-25 │ George  │ Ace       │ GH      │ AQ        ║  
║ 2015-01-26 │ George  │ Ace       │ GH      │ AQ        ║  
╚════════════╧═════════╧═══════════╧═════════╧═══════════╝
```

Comment: next time, please provide proper formating yourself

Comment: Besides the formatting this is a very good question: test scenario with full code, own effort, expected output, clear explanation. Worth an upvote!

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server?

Comment: Your code misses the inserts into table "d"...

Comment: After looking into this for a while, I must admit, that I don't get it... All rows in "d" have the `r_id=13`, so all are `Primary`. Please edit your data to provide the full logic. This points to `PIVOT` or `GROUP BY with AGGREGATE` (as you've tried it already), but your data is not compliant...

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 you can use `LAG` and `LEAD` to get the neighbours, very nice functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
WITH Pivoted AS
(
    SELECT d.calldate AS calldate
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name='Primary' THEN e.NAME END) AS [Primary]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name='Secondary' THEN e.NAME END) AS [Secondary]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name='Primary' THEN e.initial END) AS [PrimINIT]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name='Secondary' THEN e.initial END) AS [SeconINIT]
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN e ON a.e_id=e.id
    INNER JOIN r ON a.r_id=r.id
    INNER JOIN d ON a.d_id=d.id
    INNER JOIN s ON a.s_id=s.id
    GROUP BY d.calldate
)
,WithNeighbours AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ISNULL(LAG([Primary]) OVER(ORDER BY calldate,[Primary]),'') AS PrevPrim 
          ,ISNULL(LAG([Secondary]) OVER(ORDER BY calldate,[Secondary]),'') AS PrevSecon
          ,ISNULL(LEAD([Primary]) OVER(ORDER BY calldate,[Primary]),'') AS NxtPrim 
          ,ISNULL(LEAD([Secondary]) OVER(ORDER BY calldate,[Secondary]),'') AS NxtSecon
    FROM Pivoted
)
SELECT calldate 
      ,[Primary]
      ,[Secondary]
      ,CASE WHEN [Primary]<>PrevPrim OR [Primary]<>NxtPrim THEN PrimINIT ELSE '' END AS PrimINIT
      ,CASE WHEN [Secondary]<>PrevSecon OR [Secondary]<>NxtSecon THEN SeconINIT ELSE '' END AS SeconINIT
FROM WithNeighbours
ORDER BY calldate
```

The result with the data given

```
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| calldate   | Primary | Secondary | PrimINIT | SeconINIT |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-09 | Jack    | Mike      | JM       | MM        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-10 | Jack    | Mike      |          |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-11 | Jack    | Mike      |          |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-12 | Jack    | Mike      |          |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-13 | Jack    | Mike      |          | MM        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-14 | Jack    | George    | JM       | GH        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-15 | Mike    | George    | MM       |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-16 | Mike    | George    |          |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-17 | Mike    | George    | MM       | GH        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-18 | George  | Ace       | GH       | AQ        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-19 | George  | Ace       |          |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-20 | George  | Ace       | GH       | AQ        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-21 | Ace     | Bill      | AQ       | BK        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-22 | Ace     | Bill      |          | BK        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-23 | Ace     | Mike      |          | MM        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-24 | Ace     | Mike      | AQ       | MM        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-25 | George  | Ace       | GH       | AQ        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-01-26 | George  | Ace       | GH       | AQ        |
+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Great Work. Question what does LAG and LEAD do?

Comment: @CiberLover007 find the neighbours in an ordered list. Therefore you must specify the OVER clause